# SQL Server 2008 - insert into column from 2 different tables

Tags: sql-server

I am wondering how I would have a single column, for example called `ClientID`, I want to be able to select from two different tables and have all the results go into this column.

This is what I am currently trying but I am getting errors:

```
SELECT ClientID = ('basic' + CAST(a.BasicCID as VARCHAR(15))) AND =('premium' + CAST(c.PremiumCID as VARCHAR(15)))
```

I want the output to display something like this

```
ClientID   Name
-------  --------
basic1   John
basic2   Pat
premium1 Mary
premium2 Sean
```

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, You can do something like this -

```
Insert into YourTable(ClientID, Name)
  SELECT 'basic' + CAST(a.BasicCID as VARCHAR(15)), Name From BasicTable a
  UNION
  SELECT 'premium' + CAST(c.PremiumCID as VARCHAR(15)), Name From PremiumTable c
```

Comment: I think it rather should be `UNION`